# C# constructor with json style arguments

Tags: c#, .net

I have been watching a PluralSight video on Generics in C# (so doesnt cover this code specifically) and the example code has a constructor set out in a manner which I've never seen before:

```
public CircularBuffer()
    : this(capacity: 10)
{
}

public CircularBuffer(int capacity)
{
  // Other code here
}
```

The constructor is called like so

```
var cb = new CircularBuffer(capacity: 3);
```

What is this notation and when was it introduced? Are there any special considerations when using it? What is it there for and what benefit does it have over existing solutions?

Comment: Those are 'named arguments' and can also be usaed for method calls, see [Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is named ["Named Arguments"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) and was introduced with .NET 4.0.

It has been introduced together with optional arguments and is most relevant in this scenario. With the named argument syntax, you can provide values for *some* of the optional arguments without the need to supply values for the others.

No special considerations are necessary, this is strictly syntactic sugar that is used by the compiler.

Comment: Also this is the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx